# Swift + WKWebView: How to prevent visits to certain URLs?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a controller that has an instance of WKWebView. However, I want it to not load any requests to Yahoo. It used to work with UIWebView (commented out below). I can't figure out how to do it using WKWebView.

```
class WebBrowserViewController: UIViewController {

  let webView = WKWebView()

  override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    self.view = self.webView
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    webView.navigationDelegate = self

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
  }
}

extension WebBrowserViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
  func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    // this prints the right thing, but it doesn't allow me to stop the request
    print(webView.URL?.absoluteString)
  }
}

// WHAT I USED TO HAVE:

//extension WebBrowserViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {
//  func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
//    
//    if visitingYahoo(request.URL?.absoluteString) {
//      return false
//    } else {
//      return true
//    }
//  }
//}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I eventually did this:

```
extension WebBrowserViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
  func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    print(webView.URL?.absoluteString)
    if urlVideoType(webView.URL!) != VideoUrl.Unknown {
      loadVideo(webView.URL!)
      decisionHandler(.Cancel) //<------------------ this part
    }
    decisionHandler(.Allow) //<------------------ this part
  }
}
```

Comment: what about if url is part of webpage, like loading an image?